# Camera intent WebView android

Tags: android, webview

Am trying to handle file upload inside `webView`. So far, am able to navigate to file manager when button is clicked, but it doesn't give option to select from camera. How do I go about this?

```
private var filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?): Boolean {
                startActivityForResult(fileChooserParams?.createIntent(), CHOOSE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
                this@MainActivity.filePathCallback = filePathCallback
                return true
            }
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            CHOOSE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data))
                    filePathCallback = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```